# PDF to Word conversion - issues with editing Word file

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I frequently convert PDFs into MS Word using Acrobat Pro XI.  The conversions usually preserve the content and formatting quite well.  But, editing the file within Word 2010 or 2013 has some issues.  I'm wondering how to fix:

1) Some (but not all) tables can be unwieldy to edit.  Typing new text is often be very slow with characters appearing one or two seconds after keypress.  Some cells will force words into a vertical orientation, one character per line per cell.  The tab stops under View Ruler are different per cell.  Moving them around can fix some problems but not the slow typing response.  In any case, this is very hard to do on large tables since the tab stops have to be modified cell-by-cell

- All in all, it seems like the table is embedded into another, larger table yet Table Properties doesn't give sufficient insight into the structure to say for certain

2) Adding sticky notes under Track Changes brings the slow character response for some, but not all, comments that I add.

What I've tried:
a) Enabling the Selection pane to see if there are hidden objects that could be taxing the system
- Don't see anything obvious
b) Saving the file into the current .docx format (removing the Compatibility Mode in the Title Bar)
- No improvement
c) Compressing pictures to try to reduce file size
- No improvement
d) Applying a standard Word table layout
- No improvement
e) Looking at Table Properties
- Setting changes don't fix the problems
f) Looking at the underlying XML file
- There might be something there for the native XML speaker but I couldn't find anything
g) Looking for conversion settings in Acrobat Pro
- Nothing obvious

Exporting to Powerpoint sometimes yields better table conversions so I have been doing table edits there and putting the table back into Word with some success.  I'd prefer to stay within one application if possible.

Comment: When you export from Acrobat, do you export to `DOC` or `DOCX`? Try both, they sometimes yield slightly different results. We extract PDFs on an almost daily basis and there is no easy, one size fits all solution.

Comment: Good point - I export to .docx.  I will try .doc and see if that helps.